# What is the right way to query all Notes & Attachments?

Tags: soql, lightning

I would like to query all notes & attachments, lets say for an Account.
I uploaded 2 different files in the notes and attachment area but if I do the query:

```
select id from attachment
```

I do not get anything back.
If I make a query against Notes:

```
select id from Note
```

same result. I get one result back but this is a different Note
The query:

```
SELECT Id, ParentId from ContentDocument
```

gives me the correct values but the ParentId is empty. Therefore, I do not know which Documents are for which accounts.

Any ideas how to query it in the right way? Currently, SF has too many different kind of "documents" like files, notes, attachments etc. from my point of view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Salesforce has two sorts of notes and attachments. There's the Classic type, represented by the `Note` and `Attachment` sObjects, and the Lightning type, represented by the Content suite of objects - `ContentDocument`, `ContentVersion`, `ContentDocumentLink`, and `ContentNote`. These two types are accessed in quite different ways.

The classic `Note` and `Attachment` records have a single polymorphic lookup to the record to which they're attached. You can query them simply:

```
List<Note> notes = [SELECT Id FROM Note WHERE ParentId = :myRecord];
List<Attachment> attachments = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :myRecord];
```

In the Lightning world of Content, the object model is quite a bit more complex. Both Notes and Attachments are represented as [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm), a parent object over potentially multiple [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) records. The `ContentDocument` is then linked to all of the locations in which it's been shared, which may be many, via [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm).

To make things even more confusing, there's a facade object, [`ContentNote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm), that acts like a `ContentDocument` with a single `ContentVersion` inherent in its `Content` field. You'll mostly have to worry about `ContentNote` if you're *adding* Notes, however.

Anyway - not to try to summarize the substantial complexity involved in the Content system - to query both Notes and Attachments in the Lightning style for some object whose Id is `myRecord`, you'd do

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :myRecord];
Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>();
for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdls) {
    documentIds.add(cdl.ContentDocumentId);
}
// ContentDocumentLink doesn't support semi-joins, which is frustrating.
List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN :documentIds];
```

This will return both `ContentNote` and regular `ContentDocument` Attachments. If you want just Notes, query on `ContentNote` rather than `ContentDocument.` If you want just Attachments and not Notes, filter on `FileType != 'SNOTE'`.

To get the actual content, for `ContentDocument`, you can execute a `ContentVersion` query against `ContentDocumentId` and `IsLatest = true`. For `ContentNote`, you can simply ask for the `Content` field in your `ContentNote` query, which is a Blob field.

To delete records, you only need to `delete` the top-level `ContentDocument` record. That will take the `ContentDocumentLink` records with it. Deleting `ContentDocumentLink` records may make an Attachment inaccessible, but it won't be deleted entirely.

Comment: Thx for this great answer! I had also found out the solution with the ContentDocumentLink and also could delete it but than only - like the name says it - the link in the account was removed but the real document still was in the system.
So in order to delete both I need to to make two dml statements right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found the solution:

```
select id, (select parentId from CombinedAttachments) from account where id...
```

than I get a list with these objects

Comment: Its still not possible to delete those attachments *aaarrrr*. Maybe this is still the wrong way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The below query will help you to get the records which have notes and attachments

```sql
SELECT ID
  ,Name
  ,(SELECT RecordType 
     FROM CombinedAttachments AS S 
     WHERE S.RecordType = 'Note' 
       OR S.RecordType = 'Attachment'
  ) 
FROM Account
```